# OfficeR/Flextable: ase_url = base_url, as_html = as_html, :

Tags: flextable, officer

Unfortulately, I cant produce a reproduceable example because this works on by dev machine but not on another. it should be asimple flex table on slides

What could be causing this in officeR/flextable
Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
  StartTag: invalid element name [68]
Calls: get_top_and_bottom_slides ... as_xml_document.character -> read_xml.raw -> doc_parse_raw

Answer (score 0):

options(encoding="UTF-8")
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'en_US.UTF-8')

solves the issue
The problem was the library was encountering different charcters when the encoding was not right.